# Nginx GET variable on MP4 files

Tags: php, variables, nginx, get

So i recently started using NGINX and was amazed how powerful it is.

So my question is:

I have a folder with MP4 files. But i want to deny all access to the files. 
I want to add a GET parameter to the url when accessing the file example:

http://www.blabla.com/MP4files/dance.mp4?Secretkey=dancingbear

The NGINX will then pass the variable to an php file that will decide if the user has access to the file or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a location into your NGINX site configuration for the MP4files folder and give it the appropriate rewrite like so?

```
location ~* .*(MP4files\/).* {
    rewrite ^.*\/(.*\.mp4).*$ /mp4Verification.php?file=$1
}
```

mp4Verification.php can then $_GET["file"] and $_GET["sk"] and handle verification and serving from within the PHP file.

I have not tested this and there is probably a better way of doing it within PHP itself and most PHP apps pass the whole URL into an index file which acts as a router and handles tasks such as you ask itself.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, sadly that didn't work. it just straight takes me to the file.
However this kinda worked but this doesn't pass the file the person is visiting, but it does pass the secretkey:
 
`rewrite ^/MP4files/(.*)$ /MP4files/mp4Verification.php?Secretkey=$1 last;`

Comment: @Sly My answer captures the filename and the key and passes them to mp4Verification under 2 different GET variables, 'file' and 'sk'. Your comment captures everything after MP4files/ so it should be passing dance.mp4?secretkey=dancingbear into your file under the get var of 'secretkey'. Is that not happening?

Comment: @Siy I updated the answer. I think I found the issue. NGINX automatically passes through query strings so it was never matching on my regex of 'secretkey' onwards. With the rewrite I changed it for, my URL of `/test/mp4files/hellto.mp4?secretkey=abcd1234` gave an output of `Array ( [file] => hellto.mp4 [secretkey] => abcd1234 )` with a `print_r($_GET)`. An issue I see with this depending on your use case, is it will always redirect an attempt into /mp4files/, this may cause an issue if you try to serve the file to a user or embed in a page. I am unsure of your complete usecase.